# I have a string 'Question', how to get an instance of class Question

Tags: ruby

```
class_name = 'Question'
instance = which_method(class_name)
```

Which method I should use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class_name = 'Question'
klass = Kernel.const_get class_name # klass holds the class Question, which is an object
instance = klass.new
```

Comment: You don't need the `to_sym`. `const_get` also accepts a string.

Comment: Totally right. For some reason I remembered it only accepted a sym. RDoc is misleading in that aspect (Module#const_get). Thanks for the clarification